# react native app api call returns network error with axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I am running axios in my react native application. Bu I keep getting this error

> Error: Network Error

I tried running the cors solution and it didn't work.

I tried setting a proxy value in package.json and that didn't work.

I tried deleting `node_modules` and then re-installed the packages and that didn't work.

The api works from postman.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've checked the other posts with this title and none of them helped.

Comment: is it https requst or http? please add more details

Comment: well the backend runs on http but the frontend is just the android emulator so i don't know if the frontend is running on https or not

Comment: not sure but see if this helps https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29845#issuecomment-686795721

Comment: I tried that. the emulator is connected to the internet

Answer (score 0):

Had to put in the ip of my machine 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost. 
Though I uploaded my api to heroku and it still returned network error